# How do you change swagger's path with Jersey and BeanConfig?

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, swagger-2.0

Is there any way of having `swagger.json` sitting somewhere else than the default location (`/swagger.json`)? Right now it's always deployed to `http://localhost:8080/swagger.json`, I'd like to have it at `http://localhost:8080/api-docs/swagger.json`

The [setup guide](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/swagger-core-jersey-2.x-project-setup) isn't much of a help. All it says is

> swagger.api.basepath should point to the context root of your API.
>   This defers from server to server and how you configured your JAX-RS
>   application

but that's for servlet config and I'm not even sure if that'd do what I want.

`BeanConfig` has a `basePath` property, but that's purely informational and changing it doesn't have any effect on the actual location.

Answer (score 3):

The `BeanConfig` base path, you don't want to change. That is what Swagger uses to create the URLs for your resource endpoints in the `swagger.json`.

What you *do* want to change is the path for resource class that serves up the `swagger.json`. This will either be [`ApiListingResource`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/listing/ApiListingResource.java) or [`ApiListingResourceJSON`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jersey/listing/ApiListingResourceJSON.java). In the majority of cases, it will most likely be the former.

To change the path, what we need to do is register it differently from how it was normally registered, as the `@Path` annotation values on the resource class is `/`. So if we register like any other resource class, it will always be the same as the root path to our Jersey application.

Jersey has an API that allows us to [build resources programmatically](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/resource-builder.html). So we can build a resource from the `ApiListingResource` and just change the path

```
final Resource.Builder builder = Resource.builder(ApiListingResource.class);
// note, this path will be relative your base path of your Jersey app
builder.path("api-docs");
final Resource apiListingResource = builder.build();
```

Then just register the `Resource` with your `ResourceConfig`.

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
resourceConfig.registerResources(apiListingResource);
```

One thing you need to be sure not to do, is disable the [`SwaggerSerializers`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/listing/SwaggerSerializers.java#L20), which is used to serialize the `Swagger` object to the `swagger.json`. For instance if you registered swagger with Jersey, by scanning the `io.swagger.jaxrs.listing` package, both the `ApiListingResource` and the `SwaggerSerializers` are in that package, so both of them would have been registered. In our case, we should take out this package from the list of packages to scan, and just individually register the `SwahggerSerializers`

```
resourceConfig.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);
```

Comment: Thanks. Again, a really instructive and educational answer, beyond my initial question. According to Jersey's doc, that should work. However, I've tried it and swagger.json is nowhere to be found. Neither in the original nor under /api-docs, where it should be. I debugged and Jersey seems to be adding it as any other module. Any idea what could be missing?

Comment: I've tested it, and it should work. Only the resource class will be under `/api-docs`, but the resource method will still be `swagger.json`, so you need to combine them in your request `/api-docs/swagger.json`, just like your question suggests.

Comment: Also, If you're using a ResourceConfig subclass, you should be calling `registerResources` in the constructor. You shouldn't be creating another ResourceConfig instance, as I did in my example.. if that wasn't obvious.